# Java Modulus and division

Tags: java, modulus

Will someone please explain why this code returns whatever is entered in as x

```
public static void calc(int x)
 {
   if((x / 10) != 0)
   {
     calc(x / 10);
   }
   System.out.print(x % 10);
 }
```

Comment: Don't think it works for negative numbers, but yeah, for nonnegative ones this'll do that.  `x/10` is `x` with the ones digit removed, and `x % 10` is the ones digit of `x`.

Comment: forget to add that it is for any positive number

Answer (score 3):

Your `calc` method is a recursive method.

If the result of performing an `int` division is not `0`, i.e. if the number is at least `10`, then divide by `10` and call itself.

Eventually, you will reach a number that is less than `10`.  The `if` condition will be `false`, and `x % 10` will be `x` itself.  But what is `x` at this point?  It's the first digit of the number.

Then the base case finishes, and the recursive calls all call `x % 10` to print.   At each level, another digit is printed, until the original call prints the last digit.

Example:

```
calc(456)
    x is 456.
    x / 10 is 45, not 0.  Call calc(x / 10)
    calc(45)
        x is 45.
        x / 10 is 4, not 0.  Call calc(x / 10)
        calc(4)
            x is 4.
            x / 10 is 0.
            Print x % 10, or 4.
        Print x % 10, or 5.
    Print x % 10, or 6.

456
```